# Webpack Generate two css files from two entry points

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I need to generate two css files from two different scss entry files.
In the below code I have mentioned two entry points.first one contains all my custom scss file imports and the second one contains all custom bootstrap imports.

So, my requirement is to generate two separate css files like...app.css and bootstrap.css

```
entry: ["./styles/app.scss", './styles/custom-bootstrap.scss'],
rules: {
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']),
  include: PATHS.app
},
plugin: {
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV']),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(compileTimeConstantForMinification),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('./styles/app.css'),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate 2 different `.css` files, you just need 2 entry points, and 1 ExtractTextPlugin instance in the plugins section that uses a variable `[name]`:

```
entry: {
  app: './styles/app.scss',
  bootstrap: './styles/custom-bootstrap.scss'
},
rules: {
  test: /.(sass|scss)$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  }),
  include: PATHS.app
},
plugin: {
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: '[name].css' //generates "app.css" and "bootstrap.css" files
  })
}
```